# Separating time-series data into half-hour chunks

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, lubridate

I have a large continuously monitored date time column which I need to separate into half-an-hour periods.

I've tried some `r` `data.table` code to separate them, but the problem remains at the transitioning period from one period to another.

The `df` dataframe below is a minimal toy example of this data.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
driver = rep(c("foo", "bar"), each = 10L)
dt = ymd_hm(c(
  "2015-05-27 07:11", "2015-05-27 07:25", "2015-05-27 07:35", 
  "2015-05-27 07:42", "2015-05-27 07:53",
  "2015-05-27 08:09", "2015-05-27 08:23", "2015-05-27 08:39", 
  "2015-05-27 08:52", "2015-05-27 09:12",
  "2015-05-27 16:12", "2015-05-27 16:31", "2015-05-27 16:39", 
  "2015-05-27 16:53", "2015-05-27 17:29",
  "2015-05-27 17:41", "2015-05-27 17:58", "2015-05-27 18:09", 
  "2015-05-27 18:23", "2015-05-27 18:42")
)
df = data.table(driver, dt)
```

I have tried the following code to separate them:

```
df[,diff := as.integer(difftime(dt, shift(dt, 1), units = "mins")), 
   by = driver]
df[, diff := {diff[1] = 0L; diff}, driver]
df[,cum_mins := cumsum(diff), driver]
df[,cum_halfhour := round(cum_mins/30, 3), driver]
df[,flag := floor(cum_halfhour), driver]
```

The resulting table is

```
> df
    driver                  dt diff cum_mins cum_halfhour flag
 1:    foo 2015-05-27 07:11:00    0        0        0.000    0
 2:    foo 2015-05-27 07:25:00   14       14        0.467    0
 3:    foo 2015-05-27 07:35:00   10       24        0.800    0
 4:    foo 2015-05-27 07:42:00    7       31        1.033    1
 5:    foo 2015-05-27 07:53:00   11       42        1.400    1
 6:    foo 2015-05-27 08:09:00   16       58        1.933    1
 7:    foo 2015-05-27 08:23:00   14       72        2.400    2
 8:    foo 2015-05-27 08:39:00   16       88        2.933    2
 9:    foo 2015-05-27 08:52:00   13      101        3.367    3
10:    foo 2015-05-27 09:12:00   20      121        4.033    4
11:    bar 2015-05-27 16:12:00    0        0        0.000    0
12:    bar 2015-05-27 16:31:00   19       19        0.633    0
13:    bar 2015-05-27 16:39:00    8       27        0.900    0
14:    bar 2015-05-27 16:53:00   14       41        1.367    1
15:    bar 2015-05-27 17:29:00   36       77        2.567    2
16:    bar 2015-05-27 17:41:00   12       89        2.967    2
17:    bar 2015-05-27 17:58:00   17      106        3.533    3
18:    bar 2015-05-27 18:09:00   11      117        3.900    3
19:    bar 2015-05-27 18:23:00   14      131        4.367    4
20:    bar 2015-05-27 18:42:00   19      150        5.000    5
```

The `flag` column is what I want, but not exactly. The problem occurs at the transitioning rows between `flag`s. For example, at rows 3 and 4, I want the algorithm to flag row 4 as 0 because row 4 is **closer to the half-an-hour point than row 3** (cum_halfhour is 31 compared to 24). The same problem remains in rows 9 and 10.

The problem in this current algorithm is that it always **floors** the cumulative time to the 30-minutes period. But in practice, the time intervals are irregular, so realistically place the cut-off point at the nearest 30-minutes point makes more sense. As explained in the row 3 and row 4 example above.

The solution may be simple but I can't come up with it. Any suggestions to achieve this algorithm? Thank you!

Comment: So you're saying you *don't* want half hour periods then - what is the desired cut off?

Comment: @Nova Thank you for your comment. I DO want half-hour periods. But the date times are not exactly half hours, and I need some approximation. If you were classifying the `cum_mins` column into half hours, would you separate 0-24, 24-58 mins, or 0-31, 31-58 mins instead? The algorithm I am using always floors the mins below 30 minutes, but making the cut-off at the closest 30 minutes makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

On second thought, there's really no need for rolling joins here:

First, generate the data *(no real need to use `lubridate` here, `as.POSIXct` with the right format string works fine)*.

```
library(data.table)
driver = rep(c("foo", "bar"), each = 10L)
dt = as.POSIXct(c(
  "2015-05-27 07:11", "2015-05-27 07:25", "2015-05-27 07:35", 
  "2015-05-27 07:42", "2015-05-27 07:53",
  "2015-05-27 08:09", "2015-05-27 08:23", "2015-05-27 08:39", 
  "2015-05-27 08:52", "2015-05-27 09:12",
  "2015-05-27 16:12", "2015-05-27 16:31", "2015-05-27 16:39", 
  "2015-05-27 16:53", "2015-05-27 17:29",
  "2015-05-27 17:41", "2015-05-27 17:58", "2015-05-27 18:09", 
  "2015-05-27 18:23", "2015-05-27 18:42")
  , format = "%F %H:%M", tz = "America/Chicago")

df = data.table(driver, dt)
```

Manipulation as follows should get what you're after:

```
## Create a column with epoch time so we don't have to worry about
## some of the idiosyncracies of the R `difftime` class
df[,dt_epoch := as.integer(dt)]
## Create a cum_halfhour column based on epoch time
df[,cum_halfhour := round((dt_epoch - min(dt_epoch))/1800,3), by = .(driver)]
## Create a rounded version
df[,nearest_half := round((dt_epoch - min(dt_epoch))/1800,0), by = .(driver)]
## Create a flag for changes using `data.table::rleid` for each driver
df[,flag := rleid(nearest_half) - 1L, by = .(driver)]

df
#     driver                  dt   dt_epoch cum_halfhour nearest_half flag
#  1:    foo 2015-05-27 07:11:00 1432728660        0.000            0    0
#  2:    foo 2015-05-27 07:25:00 1432729500        0.467            0    0
#  3:    foo 2015-05-27 07:35:00 1432730100        0.800            1    1
#  4:    foo 2015-05-27 07:42:00 1432730520        1.033            1    1
#  5:    foo 2015-05-27 07:53:00 1432731180        1.400            1    1
#  6:    foo 2015-05-27 08:09:00 1432732140        1.933            2    2
#  7:    foo 2015-05-27 08:23:00 1432732980        2.400            2    2
#  8:    foo 2015-05-27 08:39:00 1432733940        2.933            3    3
#  9:    foo 2015-05-27 08:52:00 1432734720        3.367            3    3
# 10:    foo 2015-05-27 09:12:00 1432735920        4.033            4    4
# 11:    bar 2015-05-27 16:12:00 1432761120        0.000            0    0
# 12:    bar 2015-05-27 16:31:00 1432762260        0.633            1    1
# 13:    bar 2015-05-27 16:39:00 1432762740        0.900            1    1
# 14:    bar 2015-05-27 16:53:00 1432763580        1.367            1    1
# 15:    bar 2015-05-27 17:29:00 1432765740        2.567            3    2
# 16:    bar 2015-05-27 17:41:00 1432766460        2.967            3    2
# 17:    bar 2015-05-27 17:58:00 1432767480        3.533            4    3
# 18:    bar 2015-05-27 18:09:00 1432768140        3.900            4    3
# 19:    bar 2015-05-27 18:23:00 1432768980        4.367            4    3
# 20:    bar 2015-05-27 18:42:00 1432770120        5.000            5    4
```

---

*Previously posted (overly complex) Manipulation Steps:*

```
## Create a column with epoch time so we don't have to worry about
## some of the idiosyncracies of the R `difftime` class
df[,dt_epoch := as.integer(dt)]
## Create a cum_halfhour column based on epoch time
df[,cum_halfhour := round((dt_epoch - min(dt_epoch))/1800,3), by = .(driver)]

## Create a lookup table with all the possible half hour increments for each driver
Lookup <- df[,.(half_points = seq(from = 0,
                                 to = max(cum_halfhour),
                                 by = 1)), by = .(driver)]

## Create a copy of the target half_points column since the join process
## treats the keys in a way that makes the join columns complicated to access
Lookup[,join_half_points := half_points]

## Set keys on our original table and the Lookup table
setkey(df,driver,cum_halfhour)
setkey(Lookup,driver,join_half_points)

## This one is a doozy. To get an idea of what we're assigning to the
## `half_point` column, run `Lookup[df, roll = "nearest"]`
## to see the table generated by the rolling join. We then pull
## the column `half_points` out of the joined result and assign it to the
## original `df` as a new column,
df[,half_point := Lookup[df,half_points, roll = "nearest"]]

## Create a flag using `data.table::rleid` for each driver
df[,flag := rleid(half_point) - 1L, by = .(driver)]
```